# jcombobox populate with hashmap

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jcombobox

I want to fill my combobox with a display value and a number value

```
HashMap<Integer, String> databaseList
```

I would to display the string in the combobox but the value of the comboxbox must be integer.
I know this is posible in c# is this also possible in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to fill my combobox with a display value and a number value

I would create a separate Object to contain the two properties and then add these indivdual objects to the combo box.

Check out [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for an example of this approach.

> jcombobox populate with hashmap

Otherwise you will need to create a custom `ComboBoxModel`.

This would be more difficult to do since a Hashmap doesn't have a sequential ordering of the data that you can access directly, unless your Integer is a sequential number starting at 0.

You would then also need to implement a custom method to get the String value of any combo box item.

Answer (score 0):

Values of JComboBox can be anything, since it's generic template.

```
JComboBox<String> combobox = new JComboBox<>();
String str = "string part";
int i = 7;
combobox.addItem(str + i);
```

Or you can make your pair class and use that as template argument for combobox.